# When logged in, pages from tags that are now synonyms do not render

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

I noticed in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=profile) that one of the rarest badge I hold is for the tag [gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk). Indeed, [just four people got it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4567/gawk)... and no more people will be able to, since [it is now a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/synonyms) of [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk).

The thing here is that if then I tried to browse through [gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk) by clicking on this icon (that is, going to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk?tab=Newest), I could not. I did it while logged in, both with Safari and Chrome, and it did not work. However, if opened without an open session it just redirects to Awk's page (the one that [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) points to).

If I `curl` with the console it works also (it is the no-login case):

```
$ curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk?tab=Newest
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/questions/tagged/awk">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I checked with other synonyms I know such as [bash-alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash-alias) and the behaviour is the same.

So this happens to me with Safari 11 and Chrome 71. Also, and since it was mentioned in comments, I do have the [Custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/209901) feature enabled.

Comment: I see *The page is not redirecting properly* indeed. The page redirects to itself: `Location: /questions/tagged/gawk?tab=Newest`...

Comment: And indeed, I can go to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julialang?tab=Newest`, a new synonym, and it redirects to itself too. Tsk tsk. Anonymous users go to the correct target.

Comment: Repro in Safari 12. Error as follows: `Too many redirects occurred trying to open "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk?tab=Newest". This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which is then redirected to open the original page`. There seems to be an infinite loop of redirects.

Comment: Hmm. This works for me in Chrome latest on Windows 10. [[tag:gawk]] redirects properly to [[tag:awk]], as do all other synonyms I tried.

Comment: works in Chorme Version 71.0.3578.98 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit) as well for [gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk) ..I land on [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) when logged in

Comment: Can't repro. I go to the correct page. Firefox 65.0

Comment: I can still reproduce this. Chrome and Firefox on iOS, and Chrome, Safari and Firefox on OSX. This is not a browser issue.

Comment: Hypothesis: I have the [“custom question lists” feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781) enabled. I bet that those that can’t reproduce this do not. The feature has a lag in enabling it (I think a dev has to flip you to the test group) so I can’t easily verify this, but my sock account doesn’t have that switched on and there the redirect works correctly. My sock account has requested the feature be enabled so I can hopefully confirm this soon. The `?tab=Newest` query parameter string also points to that feature, with the feature disabled the tag pages use `?sort=...`.

Comment: **Issue also reported on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323649/clicking-on-the-synonym-tag-throws-error-page-about-cookies-with-custom-questio?noredirect=1#comment1058199_323649**

Comment: I suspect @Martijn's hypothesis is correct. I have never opted into the "custom question lists" feature.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good one. I also have the custom question lists feature enabled.

Comment: Repro here, also opted-in. Using Mac High Sierra 10.13.4, FF65.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This embarrassing bug has been fixed.

This was only affecting CQL-enabled users because the non-CQL code has a different generator.

[image: screenshot showing that the function producing the URL was straight-up ignoring the tag parameter.]